# I am getting TemplateDoesNotExist error in Django version 4.0

Tags: django

```
urls file
from django.urls import path
from django.urls.resolvers import URLPattern
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('hello/', views.say_hello),
    path('name/', views.name),
    path('tp/', views.tp)
]
```

#views file
def tp(request):
return render(request, 'TP.html')

Comment: Share the filetree that includes the view and the template.

Comment: ───blog
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───__pycache__
├───mysite
│   └───__pycache__
└───playground
    ├───migrations
    │   └───__pycache__
    ├───Template
    └───__pycache__

Comment: share this is in on main qustion

Answer (score 0):

According to your file structure, you have your templates in a directory called `Template`.

However, Django by default looks for a directory named `templates`.

You can update the name of your `Template` folder OR

In your `settings.py`

```py
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(SETTINGS_PATH, 'Template'),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `Tempalte` file name `tempalte` to `Tempaltes`

Comment: That seems to be misspellings of yours ("Tempaltes"). Please use copy-paste instead of typing.